# Using variables with JSON with Python Requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to send JSON using variables to an API. When hard coded it works fine (I.E. "videos" : "30" , or "views" : "100") but now that I replaced it with variables the server responds with:

> {u'message': u"'vars' parameter is not a valid JSON"}

Here is my code:

```
return requests.post(
    "https://api.website.com",
    auth=('api', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
    data={'subscribed': True,
          'address': email,
          'name': username,
          'description': profile,
          'vars': '{"logo" : logo , "status" : status , "videos": videos , "views": views , "likes": likes}'  })
```

Comment: It's because you didn't really replace it with variables, they're still strings. the `logo` inside the string is just the character sequence 'logo' not a reference to your variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't produce json manually. Use the built in json module.

```
import json
data={'subscribed': True,
      'address': email,
      'name': username,
      'description': profile,
      'vars': json.dumps({"logo" : logo , "status" : status , "videos": videos , "views": views , "likes": likes})  })
```